# How to get secondlast element from URL using regular expression

Tags: android, regex

I have got a solution to get last element from URL:

```
public static String getLastBitFromUrl(final String url){
    // return url.replaceFirst("[^?]*/(.*?)(?:\\?.*)","$1);" <-- incorrect
    return url.replaceFirst(".*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
}
```

E.g. `www.foo.com/id` will give me `id`, but what if I want `id1` from `www.foo.com/id1/id2`?

What changes do I have to make to regular expression?

Comment: Is there a reason it must be a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is without regex. Try this:

`String url = "www.foo.com/id1/id2";

String idArray = url.split("/");

String id1 = idArray[1];`

This will split the string with the given parameter i.e., "/". So idArray[1] will give you first id.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regex-based solution, the corrected solution will be:

```
public static String getLastBitFromUrl(final String url){
    return url.replaceFirst("[^/]*/([^/?]+).*", "$1");
}

//...
System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl("www.foo.com/id"));      // => id
System.out.println(getLastBitFromUrl("www.foo.com/id1/id2")); // => id1
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/EpG7Zr)

The main point is that `.*` matches the whole string first, and then backtracks checking for a `/`. So, you match the last `/`. To get the first `/`, you do not need the `replaceFirst` method, you can use `replaceAll`, but with `[^/]*` negated character class with `*` quantifier meaning *match all characters but `/` zero or more times*.